# set translateZ value based on variable height of element

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have created a rotating cube effect using 3D css transformations. In order to achieve this I have this transform on a child element:

```
transform:  translateY(-50%) translateZ(-75px) rotateX(90deg) ;
```

and this on the parent element:

```
transform-origin: center center -75px;
```

The whole code is here: https://codepen.io/willdelphia/pen/JZOpMJ

As you can see I am using a constant "-75px" in two places. This is because the height of parent element is 150px. I am looking for a way (ideally just through CSS) to achieve the same effect but with an element of any height.

So essentially what I would like is to calculate half of the height of any give element and then use that value in the places where I have 75px.

Is this possible in CSS? Would I need to rely on javascript? Is there another way to achieve the same effect that can take elements of any size?

Comment: Is your  `parent's` height variable or fixed?

Comment: In the example I linked it is fixed. Though I would like it to be able to be variable.

Comment: In lieu of a more complete answer, since using percentages is out because the z value for `transform-origin` can't be a percent, I would say check out CSS variables (Google it). Then you gotta decide if browser support for that is good enough for you: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the child element, just change the style to this

```
transform-origin: center bottom;
transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
```

Changing the transform origin, now all the movement is done in the Y axis, instead of 50%% on Y and 50% on Z.

About the parent, it's a little bit harder. Instead of setting a transform origin, move the element to be on the center of rotation, rotate it, and move it back to the original position. All this can be done then relative to Y (notice than only the central rotation changes):

```
.flipper {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%) rotateX(0deg) translateY(50%) rotateX(-90deg);

}

.item:hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(50%) rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

.item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    perspective: 400px;

}

.flipper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%) rotateX(0deg) translateY(50%) rotateX(-90deg);

}

.item:hover .flipper {
    position: relative;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(50%) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.cubefront{
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cubetop{
    z-index: 0;

    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg) ;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(62, 62, 62);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cubefront, .cubetop {
    /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    
}

#item1 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(179, 45, 45);
}


#item2 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(179, 103, 45);

}

#item3 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(179, 148, 45);
}

#item4 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(157, 179, 45);
}

#item5 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(74, 179, 45);
}

#item6 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(45, 179, 132);
}

#item7 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(45, 159, 179);
}

#item8 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(45, 99, 179);
}
#item9 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(45, 49, 179);
}
#item10 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(87, 36, 170);
}
#item11 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(137, 36, 170);
}
#item12 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(170, 36, 143);
}
#item13 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(170, 36, 103);
}
#item14 .cubefront {
    background: rgb(170, 36, 36);
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex">
        <div id="item1" class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item3"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item4"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item5"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div id="item6"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div id="item7"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div id="item8"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div id="item9"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item10"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item11"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item12"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item13"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item14"  class="item">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="cubefront"></div>
                <div class="cubetop">
                    <div class="text">
                        Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code works. I am still trying to get my head around exactly _how_ it works. :)

Comment: Sorry, my english sometimes is not as good as I would like it to be. I have tried to explain it, but ......

Comment: Your explanation was certainly fine. I am simply having a difficult time visualizing each successive transformation in: 'rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%) rotateX(0deg) translateY(50%) rotateX(-90deg)'